# extract and compare block of text

Tags: bash, perl

I have a data gethered in one file organised in blocks

```
---- BLOCK ONE ----
some data
another data
more data
more data
-------------------

---- BLOCK two ----
some data
another data
-------------------

---- BLOCK THREE ----
some data
another data
more data
-------------------
```

and so one. togethere around 2000 blocks.

I need to extract those blocks which have less then 4 entries (data lines).
Any idea how to do it (perl prefered ; )

Comment: extract them to what?  individual files?  with what filenames?

Comment: just print them out so I can test it and redirect to the files when all ok.

Comment: just printing them all to stdout doesn't actually split them.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the output you expect. Also, please clarify if you just want "bad" blocks printed to stdout or if you need something more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple one liner:

```
$ perl -00 -lne '@k=(/\n/mg); print if $#k < 4 ' file
---- BLOCK two ----
some data
another data
-------------------

---- BLOCK THREE ----
some data
another data
more data
-------------------
```

The `-00` turns on "paragraph mode" which treats each block of lines separated by an empty line as a single "line". The `-l` adds a newline character to each `print` call and strips trailing newlines from each input "line", and the `-n` means "run the script given by `-e` on each line of the input".

The script itself looks for `\n` characters in the input "line" (paragraph) and stores them in an array. Then, if the largest index of the array is less than 4, we print the line. Remember that arrays start counting at `0`, so this means that if we have less than 4, since the first line is also counted, but the last one is not because its trailing newline has been removed by `-l`, then we have fewer than 4 lines inside the block.

Comment: +1. we may have interpreted the question differently, but this is still a good answer.

Comment: nice one. thanks a lot :)

Comment: @eswues you're welcome, but please clarify what you need in your question. Also, if one of the answers here solved your issue, please take a moment and [accept it](//unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking on the checkmark on the left. That is the best way to express your thanks on the Stack Exchange sites.

Answer (score 2):

```perl
$ perl -00 -F'\n' -n -e '
  $file = shift @F;
  pop @F;
  if (@F < 4) {
    $file =~ s/^---- | ----//g;
    open(OUT, ">", $file.".txt");
    print OUT join("\n", @F), "\n"
  }' input.txt
```

This perl one-liner uses `-00` to read the input in paragraph mode (separated by two-or-more newlines), `-F` to auto-split the input on newlines into array @F, and `-n` to auto-read the input without printing it (similar to `sed -n`).

First it uses shift to get the first element of @F into variable $file.  Then pop @F to discard the last element (`-------------------`).  If there are less than 4 elements remaining, then: remove the `----`  and  `----` from $file, open "$file.txt" for write, and print the remainder of the array to that file.

If you don't like those filenames, you can use some other method - e.g. increment a counter variable, something like `$file = sprintf "file%04i.txt", ++$counter` inside the `if` block instead of using the `s///` operator.

BTW, if you want to keep the `---- BLOCK...` header and the `------*` footer then replace the `shift` and `pop` lines with `$file = $F[0]` and change the `if` test to `if (@F < 6)`.

Sample output (using `tail` so that it prints the filenames):

```
$ tail BLOCK*.txt
==> BLOCK THREE.txt <==
some data
another data
more data

==> BLOCK two.txt <==
some data
another data
```

---

Same thing as a standalone script, but using a counter to generate the filename:

```perl
$ cat split-blocks.pl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
my $counter;

$/='';

while(<<>>) {
  my @lines = split /\n/;
  my $file = shift @lines;
  pop @lines;

  if (@lines < 4) {
    $file = sprintf 'file%04i.txt', ++$counter
    open(OUT, ">", $file) || die "couldn't open $file for write: $!\n";
    print OUT join("\n", @lines), "\n"
  }
};

$ ./split-blocks.pl input.txt

$ tail file*
==> file0001.txt <==
some data
another data

==> file0002.txt <==
some data
another data
more data
```

Comment: Are you sure the OP wants these printed to separate files? That doesn't seem clear at all in the question and they left a message talking about STDOUT.

Comment: I don't see how there could be any other meaning for "extract".   Just re-printing them to stdout doesn't extract each block of text.

Comment: What do you mean? "Extract the bad blocks from the file and print them to stdout" seems perfectly reasonable. Anyway, I asked the OP for clarification, let's see what we get.

Comment: @terdon The OP also said "redirect to the file**s**" (plural), and that's not going to be possible outside of this script - not without printing them to stdout separated by paragraphs or something and then writing another script to split them afterwards.   Also, these example scripts also allow for doing other things with the data lines inside the `if` code block, not just saving the text blocks to individual files.

Comment: Oh sure, your answer does that and then some. I just understand this as simply needing to check for the presence of bad blocks before doing something else.

Answer (score 0):

```perl
perl -lne '
    if (/^-+$/) {
        print join "\n", @M, $_ if $#M < 4;
        @M = ();
        next;
    }

    if (/^-/) {
        $M[0] = $_;
        next;
    }

    push @M, $_ if $#M >= 0;
' file
```

Read the file with `perl` line by line thanks to `perl` auto-printing option disabled `(-n)`.

Then if we are inside a section `(push @M, $_ if $#M >= 0)` push the line inside an array.

If we are inside the ending secion `(/^-+$/)` and the array length is less then 4 then print it and empty the array `(@M = ())`.

Otherways we begin a section `(/^-/)` and so save the current line as the first value in the array, and os it becomes the header.

---

I have deleted the empty lines but you can kept it if desire.

Answer (score 0):

Using any `awk`:

```
awk 'NF && !/^-/{ buf= buf (data?ORS:"") $0; data++ }
          /^-+$/{ if(data<4) { print (ors?ORS:"") buf; ors=ORS }; buf=data="" }' infile
```

Output:

```
some data
another data

some data
another data
more data
```

If you wanted to keep the blocks header/footer:

```
awk 'NF{ buf= buf (data?ORS:"") $0; data++ }
 /^-+$/{ if(data<=5) { print (ors?ORS:"") buf; ors=ORS }; buf=data="" }' infile
```

Output:

```
---- BLOCK two ----
some data
another data
-------------------

---- BLOCK THREE ----
some data
another data
more data
-------------------
```